# Remove "old" associations with saveAll

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a problem with assocations, i.e. a Project which "hasMany" Links. The project edit page has fields for the Project itself and some for associated Links:

```
echo $form->input('Link.0.url');
echo $form->input('Link.1.url');
echo $form->input('Link.2.url');
```

In the Project controller I use $this->Project->saveAll($this->data), which saves the Project and three associated links. Fine. Now while updating Projects I want to be able to delete some links. I want to keep it simple and remove all Link.n.* using jQuery for example. Unfortunately this doesn't work as expected: The removed association still exists after using saveAll, even though it is not given in $this->data anymore.

CakePHP is very specific in saving associations. Sadly I cannot find something about removing them. I hope somebody understands my problem and has an idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is already in the database you will need to use delete() or deleteAll()

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought I had read something about that old associations are removed automatically when using saveAll. But this should work, thank you.